# What are the cost imlications of snapshotChanges() when value is changed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a collection of 5 items in firestore and I query them using this method.

```
afs.collection('path').snapshotChanges().subscribe(a=>{
    console.log(a)
})
```

When I make changes to a single document the console log will display all 5 items again.

So my question is: does this mean I get charged 5 reads for the initial query before any changes and then 1 write for the change made and another 5 reads for the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only charged for the initial 5 documents, plus each inidividual document that is changed afterward as long as the subscriber is still attached.  Everything else is cached in memory.